# Запуск программы через планировщик

Tags: c#, .net, windows

В общем сделал программу и хочу ее повесить на планировщик задач Windows.

На машину я захожу под одним логином, но программу должна стучаться на шару под другим логином.

Если я запускаю программу от себя, то все работает четко, ведь я залогинен.

Если я запускаю ее через планировщик, то она крашится, что у нее нет доступа...

Как можно обойти этот нюанс? Пробовал через `NET USE` биндить диск, но в таком случае она ругается, что не видит этот диск.

Comment: Если используете стандартный планировщик винды, то там есть параметры от какого пользователя запускать программу.

Comment: Да, но тем не менее, эта учетка не видна на этой машине под которой я хочу обратится к шаре на другой машине.

Comment: Вроде, нашел подобную проблему и там написано, что монтирование-это фикция для пользователя в интерфейсе=> планировщик не видит.

Comment: В таком случае, можно попробовать запускать ее в планировчище от текущего пользователя, тогда, по идее, должно сработать.

Comment: А что мешает без монтирования использовать сетевой ресурс?